# How does PBS_NODEFILE work in pbs?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

For example, I have a file */home/user/nodes*, which contains:

```
node1
node2
node3
node4
...
```

When I try to submit a job like:

```
qsub -v PBS_NODEFILE=/home/user/nodes -l nodes=2
```

Does it mean that pbs will select 2 nodes from */home/user/nodes* list? I tried but it was not. It still chose the nodes from $PBS_HOME/server_priv/nodes, which is the default configuration.

I really want pbs could choose nodes from my own nodefile, is there a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a queue system the idea is you let the system assign the nodes to your job when the job runs so you will never use your 'nodes' file. At run time, the variable PBS_NODEFILE is set to the location of a file that is created for your job that includes a list of the assigned nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I got it... that makes sense. I am asking this question because I want to let pbs exclude some nodes for specific jobs. So I am wondering whether there's a way to do that...

Comment: PBS/Torque doesn't seem to have a mechanism for excluding nodes. You can request specific nodes or nodes with a certain defined property. Check the qsub man page for the '-l 'option for specifics. You may also want to check with the admin since they may have a way to solve your problem already.

Comment: Thanks, I know this part. I've been thinking about this for a long time and couldn't come up with a good solution.